# How to show conditional data in Crystal Report?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am working on Crystal Report based reciept that is generated on run time. On that process I have to perform a couple of things:

1- Printing of two reciept in a single go 
2- Showing different text in two different reciept. By different I mean that on top of the reciept I have to show text *For Customer Only* and in other printout I have to show *For Office Use Only*. On Customer Reciept I also have to show Address on bottom.

Is it possible to do? how do I do it?

Comment: I have used subreports.

Comment: Can you elaborate it further how did you do? any Blog post?

Comment: I have no blogs. I created subreport, containing entire receipt, duplicated it (export-import) to second detail section, changed required texts, linked these subreports by receipt id to main report, played with section heights and other section options, done.

Comment: So you were generating 2 reciept at the time of printing? how were you doing it?

Comment: No, I design report with two, almost identical pages (subreports).